# Debugging a WSOD in Drupal 7 even with error_reporting on in the index.php file

Tags: 7, debugging, wsod

I'm coming into a totally abused and hacked up drupal 7 project. The site is currently working on the production server, but I'm trying to migrate it to a new server. I've replicated as much as I can according to its environment, but I still get the WSOD on certain pages. However I am able to reach the admin pages and some of the other pages. I've even enabled the following in the index.php file:

error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

But I still get the WSOD. I tried to edit the html.tpl.php file to see if it even loads, but it doesn't. What are some next steps one would do to debug something of this state? It's definitely crashing before the theme tpl files are loaded. Would I use a backtrace in this scenario? But where?

Comment: Look in the server PHP and Apache error logs. Even if you aren't seeing the error on the screen, you will generally (though not always) find an error in one of those.

Comment: Anything in watchdog?

Comment: Note aswell that not all hosts allow you to change these settings. So as noted above, check server logs